# I am trying to run json_util.load_from_path but I get FileNotFoundError

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm having problems with `json_util.load_from_path` [procedure](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/available-algorithms/json_util).

I tried to to pass an absolute path with a "file:///" prefix but I get the error  `FileNotFoundError` when executing the function in my application.

My code looks something like this

```
CALL json_util.load_from_path("file:///home/mel/data/data.json") 
YIELD objects
UNWIND objects AS o
RETURN o.first_name AS name, o.last_name AS surname;
```

If it matters I'm using Memgraph docker image (pure one, not the Platform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re running Memgraph with Docker, JSON file has to be located in the Docker container. Ideally, you would copy your file to `/usr/lib/memgraph` with `docker cp file.json <container_id>:/usr/lib/memgraph/file.json`
Then you would have `CALL json_util.load_from_path("/usr/lib/memgraph/file.json")` as a part of your query.